# MySQL 3.23 on Centos 6?

Tags: centos, mysql

Don't ask why, just is it possible to install old mysql 3.23 on new CentOS 6.4 i386 or x64 version (same to me)?

Answer (score 1):

Searched on this one for a while. Not finding anything older than 4.1.

- ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/databases/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-4.1/

Your only option will be to find the Linux Generic Architecture Independent builds which are designed to run self contained from a directory. We've used these in the past and they work well.

Continuing the search I'm not finding it as available. I searched Google using this:

- [intitle:"index of *" mysql- tar.gz](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&q=intitle%3a%22index%20of%20%2a%22%20mysql-%20tar.gz&oq=intitle%3a%22index%20of%20%2a%22%20mysql-%20tar.gz&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.58095.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..26.serp..0.0.0._fSimBVUuWA)